# Adding item as array in session array in php

Tags: php

I am working on a shopping cart project, and I am adding some items in session as array but when I add one item, then it is displaying two items, code is as below :-

```
  if(!empty($_GET['pid'])) {
      if(!empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {
            $item = array($_GET['id'], $_GET['pid'], $_GET['item_weight'], $_GET['item_quantity'], $_GET['per_item_price'], $_GET['total_price'], $_GET['savings'], $_GET['product_name'], $_GET['type']);
            $index = count($_SESSION['cart']);
            $_SESSION['cart'][$index] = $item;      
      } else {
            $item = array($_GET['id'], $_GET['pid'], $_GET['item_weight'], $_GET['item_quantity'], $_GET['per_item_price'], $_GET['total_price'], $_GET['savings'], $_GET['product_name'], $_GET['type']);
            $_SESSION['cart'] = array($item);
      }      
  }
```

Any idea what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Maybe this code is not wrong but the process is. Are your sure your are not excuting this code twice?

Comment: You shouldn't send `$_GET['total_price']` - anyone can hack your eshop by simple url editing.

Comment: But your problem is you have used array 2 times .. because `$item` is already in the form of array.. again your are trying to store array to `$_SESSION['cart']`. try `$_SESSION['cart'] = $item; `

Comment: @MoorthyGK `$_SESSION['cart']` is a 2-dimensional array. It's an array of items, and each item is an array of parameters.

Comment: OT: You should use an associative array for `$item`. Numeric arrays should be used for homogeneous lists, collections of related data should be associative arrays.

Comment: @Barmar well really he should use a "cart" object or some such instead of an array, but i presume he's just learning

Answer (score 0):

you can do this much more simply using `[]` to push items to your array:

```
$_SESSION['cart'][] = array(
    'some' => 'stuff'
);
```

Comment: This is equivalent to what he wrote, so how will it fix the problem?

Comment: @Barmar as posted, the code can't ever repeat, but simplifying the code will make it easier for him to debug

Comment: Anyway it's not an answer to the question. You should have added a comment.

Answer (score -3):

But your problem is you have used array 2 times .. because `$item` is already in the form of array.. again your are trying to store array to `$_SESSION['cart']`

```
        $item = array($_GET['id'], $_GET['pid'], $_GET['item_weight'], $_GET['item_quantity'], $_GET['per_item_price'], $_GET['total_price'], $_GET['savings'], $_GET['product_name'], $_GET['type']);
        //$_SESSION['cart'] = array($item);
        $_SESSION['cart'] = $item;
```

Comment: He's not adding values to the array, he's initializing it as an array of values.

Comment: You are asigning `$item` to `$_SESSION['cart']` while the cart is an array of items.